# Правильное название классов в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Почему часто утверждают, что название классов `.page-head {} .sub-content {}` более правильное, чем `.page_head {} .sub_content {}`?
Это просто давняя традиция или действительно в этом есть большой смысл?

Comment: В плане работоспособности смысла нету, в плане удобства есть. Советую ознакомиться с [методологией БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/)

Comment: Вообще все сводится к тому что бы согласовать правила  именования классов, разметки итп и потом всем в команде придерживаться этих правил.

Comment: https://ru.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/ а гугл в своем стандарте вообще призывает не использовать ничего кроме дефиса

Comment: @RTK Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @RTK я до сих пор вижу только одну разницу, то что названия с дефисом нельзя копировать двойным кликом, а с нижним подчеркиванием можно. Тем не мнее почему-то привык писать с дефисом просто ибо так делали все когда учился.

Answer (score 3):

Для каждого языка есть свои правила оформления кода по умолчанию, наиболее употребимые. В разных языках они могут быть разные.

Например для C# функции принято именовать в `UpperCamelCase` (`PascalCase` другое название) `MyFunctionMakeThis`.
В JavaScript  `lowerCamelCase` `myFunctionMakeThis`

Я не говорю что этим правилам необходимо следовать, это решение принимает каждый сам (и каждая команда).

В случае CSS наиболее употребимым стандартом является `kebab-case`

Пример `.my-item-selector`.

В чём плюс использование стандартных правил оформления кода:

- Более простое понимание кода программистами (например новыми в компании, или вообще внешних к проекту).
- Единый стиль для разных компонент и программ.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще правильное наименование это через БЭМ. Об этом можно почитать вот [здесь](https://ru.bem.info/)

Это очень удобно, если вы используете препроцессоры (а в дальнейшем вы будете их использовать), также для элементов, которые обрабатываются какими либо скриптами задают различные префиксы 
Например: `class="header__logo js-logo-click"`
Рекомендую ознакомиться с данной методологией.

Comment: Десять раз перечитал, так ничего и не понял....

Answer (score -1):

Есть смысл, если использовать методологию БЭМ! 
Для разделения слов в именах используется дефис (-).
Элемент отделяется от блока двумя подчеркиваниями (__). Модификатор — одним (_).
Более подробно можно ознакомиться [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/276035/)